# Discrete Mathematics Cantor Set

Tags: discrete-mathematics

According to the statement of Cantor presented the lecture is the amount of power
to N is not countable, ie there uncountables set are numerous amounts of natural numbers, |P(N)| > |N|.

Show that the number of finite sets of natural numbers is countably ie
|Pfin(N)| = |N|, where Pfin(N) = {A | A ⊂ N, |A| < infinity}.

Hint: There is a simple bijection between N and Pf in(N)

I have this Cantor theorem (Cantor) for all sets X applies to | P (X) | > | X |.
(P (X) = {Y | Y ⊆ X}, potency, amount to X.

And i know that a bijection means that it exist exactly one solution.
But how can i prove this. I think in terms that {x,subset,belongs} but after that i get stuck??

Comment: Somebody this is not a easy question+??

Comment: Let $\wp_k(\Bbb N)$ be the family of subsets of $\Bbb N$ of cardinality $k$, so that $\wp_{\text{fin}}(\Bbb N)=\bigcup_{k\ge 0}\wp_k(\Bbb N)$. Show by induction on $k$ that each $\wp_k(\Bbb N)$ is countable, and then use the fact that the union of countably many countable sets is countable. For the induction you’ll want the fact that $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ is countable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that:

The set of all subsets with 1 element is countable (of course, since that set is $\{\{1\},\{2\},...\}$ so that is a listing right there)

You can the show that the set of al subsets with <= 2 elements is countable. To do this, you go through a standard trick to show that all pairs (x,y) are countable where each of  x and y come froma countable set (not necessarily the same) ... I am sure your book or teacher has shown you some kind of'zig-zag' picture where you go through all the elements of a 2-dimensional array where the elements on both axes are countable.

You can now do the same to get all sets with <= 3 elements: put the countable sets of sbsets with 1 element on one axis, and the set of all subsets with <= 2 elements on the othr axis, and the entries of course being the union of tose sets, and zig-zag throug those to get the set of all subsets wih <= 3 elements ... So that is a countable set as well.

This of course can now be repeated for any n. That is, by induction you can show that for any n, the set of all subsets S_k with <= k elements is countable.

Finally, create one more 2-dimensional array like this: have all numbers k on one axis, and have all S_1, S_2, etc on the other axis, and have the entries (i,j) be the i_th entry of a listing of S_j. Zig-zagging through that array gives you a listing of all finite subsets of N, so the set of all finite subsets of N is countable.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to first list all subsets whose elemets sum up to 1 (so that is $\{1\}$, and maybe $\{0,1\}$ if 0 is included in N), then do all subsets whose elements sum up to 2, etc etc. Since for any n there are only finitely many subsets whose lements sum up to n, you will eventually get to any subset whose members sum up to $n$ for any $n$, and since for any subset the sum of its elements is some number $n$, this listing covers all subsets of N, so the set of all subsets is countable.